# ActionListener not calls with ajax=false

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm facing a strange issue with JSF, primefaces 5.2, glassfish 4, CDI ViewScoped Named beans. I've searched the forum but mostly people got stuck with ajax not working, while here Command button actionListener works with process="@form" but with ajax="false" it does not, rather just a full page refresh occurs. What i 
understand that JSF default behavior is process="@form" but here i have to explicitly define it, without which ajax does not work. I've double checked and there are no nested forms in the hierarchy. Could it be something wrong with my development environment or am i doing something terribly wrong. Here is my jsf page

```
<h:panelGroup id="selectedtestpanel3">
                <h:form id="SelectedTests3" >                        
                    <p:dataTable id="selectedTestDataTable3" value="#{aTestRegController.testprofilelist}" var="seltestprofile" 
                                 rowKey="#{aTestRegController.selectedToString(seltestprofile)}" tableStyle="width:auto" resizableColumns="true"
                                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{aTestRegController.selected}" style="vertical-align:top;"
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{aTestRegController.testprofilePull(aTestRegController.selected)}" 
                                update="patientRegWizard:SelectedTests3, patientRegWizard:displayprices"/>

                        <p:column headerText="Test/Profile Name" width="10">
                            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfileName(seltestprofile)}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Price" width="10">
                            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfilePrice(seltestprofile)}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Container" width="10">
                            <h:outputText value="#{aTestRegController.selectedTestProfileContainer(seltestprofile)}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <p:commandButton id="saveReg" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="Save Test Registration01" 
                                     actionListener="#{aTestRegController.createVoucher()}" 
                                     disabled="#{empty aTestRegController.testprofilelist}"                                       
                                     ajax="false"
                                     />
                </h:form>                    
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Here are some lines of managed bean

```
@Named("aTestRegController")
@ViewScoped
public class ATestRegController implements Serializable  {
@EJB
private facades.PatientFacade patientFacade;
@Inject 
private facades.VoucherFacade voucherFacade;
@Inject
private facades.TestFacade testFacade;
public void createVoucher(){
    this.biolist2=null;
    this.hemolist2=null;
    this.microlist2=null;
    this.speclist2=null;
    this.radiolist2=null;      
    try{
        //if(this.getItem()!=null){
        if(true){
            tempSessionVars();
            this.item=fillVoucher();
            this.create();
            List<Voucherdetails> cashvdlist = new ArrayList<>(this.item.getVoucherdetailsCollection());
            String testprofilecashsliplist=AReportPrint.convertVoucherdetailsToString(cashvdlist);
            AReportPrint.printCashSlip(testprofilecashsliplist, item);
            iterateSelection();
            profilelist=new ArrayList();
            profilemap.clear();
            testlist=new ArrayList();
            testmap.clear();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The actionlistener is in a managed bean. I miss that in your question. Please make it an mcve

Comment: Sorry but what is an mcve?

Comment: See [ask] (and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) or just use google.